# fit numpy polynomials to noisy data

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I want to exactly represent my noisy data with a `numpy.polynomial` polynomial. How can I do that?.

In this example, I chose legendre polynomials. When I use the polynomial `legfit` function, the coefficients it returns are either very large or very small. So, I  think I need some sort of regularization.

Why doesn't my fit get more accurate as I increase the degree of the polynomial? (It can be seen that the 20, 200, and 300 degree polynomials are essentially identical.) Are any regularization options available in the polynomial package?

I tried implementing my own regression function, but it feels like I am re-inventing the wheel. Is making my own fitting function the best path forward?

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares as mini
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
tofit = np.sin(3 * x) + .6 * np.sin(7*x) - .5 * np.cos(3 * np.cos(10 * x))

# This is here to illustrate what I expected the legfit function to do
# I expected it to do least squares regression with some sort of regularization.
def myfitfun(x, y, deg):
    def fitness(a):
       return ((np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x, a) - y)**2).sum() + np.sum(a ** 2)
    return mini(fitness, np.zeros(deg)).x

degrees = [2, 4, 8, 16, 40, 200]
plt.plot(x, tofit, c='k', lw=4, label='Data')
for deg in degrees:
    #coeffs = myfitfun(x, tofit, deg)
    coeffs = np.polynomial.legendre.legfit(x, tofit, deg)
    plt.plot(x, np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x, coeffs), label="Degree=%i"%deg)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a normal polyfit? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Comment: It doesn't get more accurate because you probably need very very small coefficients for that high degrees. But they can't get any smaller than around 1e-15 or so... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

Comment: @Joe Does polyfit work on legendre polynomials? If not, it doesn't fit my problem. I edited my question to remove "any polynomial will do." As for the machine precision thing, I don't think you've diagnosed the problem correctly.

Comment: `polyfit` is just `legfit` but for regular polynomials. I have thought about this quesiton. I think this will take more than a 2-second google search to answer.

Comment: Have you tried if `polyfit` is working better than `legfit`? Do you have to use the Legendre polynomials? Or just fit the data?

Comment: Again, this question should take more than a two-second google search. Why do you think `polyfit` would be any better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Legendre polynomials are meant to be used over the interval [-1,1]. Try to replace `x` with `2*x/x[-1] - 1` in your fit and you'll see that all is good:

```
nx = 2*x/x[-1] - 1
for deg in degrees:
    #coeffs = myfitfun(x, tofit, deg)
    coeffs = np.polynomial.legendre.legfit(nx, tofit, deg)
    plt.plot(x, np.polynomial.legendre.legval(nx, coeffs), label="Degree=%i"%deg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to use the proper interval in the fit is to use the Legendre class

```
from numpy.polynomial import Legendre as L
p = L.fit(x, y, order)
```

This will scale and shift the data to the interval [-1, 1] and track the scaling factors.